# how to put a value to an array when a checkbox is checked? c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I am making a random character generator, i have 2 forms, form1 and form2, on my form2 i have the checkboxes there, so if the user checked checkbox1, on my form1 it will only display 1 character, now if the user check all 5 checkboxes, my form1 will generate 5 characters. i have a button on form1 that will trigger an event on generating random characters.

characters: '+','-','*','/','%'

how will my code be? I am using
WINDOWS FORMS APPLICATION.

pics here:
form1: http://i49.tinypic.com/30bzos8.png
form2: http://i50.tinypic.com/k00ndt.png

```
        char[] select = new char[] { '+' , '-' , '*' , '/', '%' };
        var rand = new Random();
        char num = select[rand.Next(5)];
```

Comment: What have you tried?  We like to see some attempt with code to know your thought process.  This also makes the question more "answer friendly."  Also, what value do you want to put in the array?

Comment: I have post my codes on the desription sir/maam.

Comment: That was the problem, i don't know what will i do to generate the characters. I can input them all easily, but there is a checkbox on my form2 so if the Addition(checkbox) is checked, it will only dislplay '+' whenever i press the button on form1.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not too familiar with C#.  I'm afraid I will have to have to let someone else answer this...  Sorry...

Comment: I sense a homework question.

Comment: @sidholland Yes. This is my homework, i'm actually new at this.

Comment: Which form is your startup form, I am assuming Form1, if so run Form2 using ShowDialog and when it exits check the DialogResult and if OK then read a Property on Form2 to pull the values that you selected.

Comment: @Mark Hall, no my main form is form 2

Comment: Yes you are correct do you know how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situations are always interesting since we do not know what you have or not have covered in class. So as per my comment above above in which it appears you gave conflicting answers I will assume that Form2 is being created in the Constructor of Form1 Like so.
You will need some sort of method to determine what Combobox's are checked, I just XOR'd binary values, and as I said in my Comment I would start Form2 with a ShowDialog and look at the return value to determine wether to exit or continue. I will give you a quick and dirty example, it is up to you to flesh it out. If this is not the case you will need to post a little more Code

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    char[] operators;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        if (frm2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //Check for DialogResult Here
        {
            operators = CreateArray(frm2.GetOperators); // Get ComboBox Values from Form2 and Process them
            frm2.Close();                  // Close Form2
        }
        else
            Application.Exit();           // If DialogResult is not OK then exit Form
    }

    private char[] CreateArray( int value)
    {
        string num = "";
        if ((value & 1) == 1)
            num += "+";
        if ((value & 2) == 2)
            num += "-";
        if ((value & 4) == 4)
            num += "*";
        if ((value & 8) == 8)
            num += "/";
        if ((value & 16) == 16)
            num += "%";

        return num.ToCharArray();
    }
}
```

**Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    int operators;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
        //Method that I used for determining CheckBox State. You can use a boolean array or an Enumeration ....
        if (cb.Text == "Addition")
            operators = operators ^ 1;
        else if (cb.Text == "Subtraction")
            operators = operators ^ 2;
        else if (cb.Text == "Multiplication")
            operators = operators ^ 4;
        else if (cb.Text == "Division")
            operators = operators ^ 8;
        else if (cb.Text == "Modulus")
            operators = operators ^ 16;

    }
    public  int GetOperators       //Property for return value to Form1
    {
        get { return operators; }
    }
}
```

Comment: sir this was my copy of the assignment if you want to see it. Dont mind the submission date etc. https://www.dropbox.com/s/9wxyq6ltsowjc9m/Programming%20Assignment%201.pdf?fb=1&fb_action_ids=4506187368006&fb_action_types=dropboxdropbox%3Aupdate&fb_source=other_multiline&action_object_map=%7B%224506187368006%22%3A425658030823493%7D&action_type_map=%7B%224506187368006%22%3A%22dropboxdropbox%3Aupdate%22%7D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D

Comment: @JanDarrenNoroña What I gave should work, What I did was to append the individual operator strings (how ever you pass them from Form to Form) then use the String.ToCharArray which will create your 
Array